# Django: Retrieve POST argument from password reset email

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-2.0

I'm fairly new to django and I'm currently rewriting the django login views so I can move all the authentication process to a dedicated django app where I can redefine the templates.
So currently I have an `accounts` app which `url.py` looks like that:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.password_reset,
         {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_form.html',
          'email_template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_email.html',
          'subject_template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_subject.txt',
          'post_reset_redirect': 'done/'}, name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
         {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_confirm.html',
          'post_reset_redirect': '/accounts/reset/done/'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

And a `accounts/password_reset_email.html` which looks like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
To initiate the password reset process for your {{ user.get_username }} account,
click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}?origin_page={{ request.POST.origin_page }}"

...

Sincerely,
The Team
{% endautoescape %}
```

What I want to do is to recover the `origin_page` argument so when the user click on the reset link from the email he get redirected to the right webpage after his password is reset. So far I tried to do this in `password_reset_form.html`:

```
{% block content %}
    <p>Forgotten your password? Enter your email address below, and we'll email instructions for setting a new one.</p>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="hidden" name="origin_page" value="{{ request.GET.origin_page }}"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here I just want to pass in my `origin_page` to the submit form so that I can retrieve it from `accounts/password_reset_email.html`, the url for this page looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_reset/?origin_page=/mypage/`.

How can I recover the `request.POST.origin_page` parameter from `accounts/password_reset_email.html`?
Thanks.

Comment: That's not `request.POST`, it's `request.GET`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm sending an `<input type="hidden" name="origin_page" value="{{ request.GET.origin_page }}"/>` from a form with a `post` method. Why would it be a `request.GET`? Btw I already tried both and none of the two works

Answer (score 1):

maybe that helps

```
path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='form.html',
            email_template_name='email.html',
            extra_email_context={
                'origin_page':'origin_page_thing'
            }
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
```

email:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}?origin_page={{ origin_page }}
```

E-Kami solution:

Ok I've got it, I actually created a new PasswordResetView like this: ' \

```
class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'commons/password_reset_form.html'
    email_template_name = 'commons/password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'commons/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = 'done/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_email_context = {
            'origin_page': self.request.POST['origin_page']
        }
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution. My views and urls are fine, they all work flawlessly. The only thing I would like to do on top on what is already working is to be able to retrieve my var `origin_page` from the `accounts/password_reset_email.html` template. This `origin_page` variable is passed from `password_reset_form.html` as `<input type="hidden" name="origin_page" value="{{ request.GET.origin_page }}"/>`. This is the only thing I need.

Comment: But retrieving `origin_page` with with either `request.POST.origin_page` or `request.GET.origin_page` doesn't work

Comment: It works... But now I don't know how to retrieve `origin_page_thing` from the `<input type="hidden" name="origin_page" value="{{ request.GET.origin_page }}"/>` of `form.html` here.

Comment: Ok I've got it, I actually created a new `PasswordResetView` like this:

class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'commons/password_reset_form.html'
    email_template_name = 'commons/password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'commons/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = 'done/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_email_context = {
            'origin_page': self.request.POST['origin_page']
        }
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: If you could edit your response including the modified class I just posted I'll mark you as the valid answer, there is no way for me to format this well enough in the comments :(